# sqlite3 database file size problem

Tags: database, sqlite

i have sqlite3 database file, that is back-end of a blog.

The blog has about 20 articles right now and no BLOBs are stored, just posts, comments etc.

The size of file should be about 1 Mb, but in reality, it is 470 MB.

Why it is so huge ?

How can i find places, eating up space ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you been doing a lot of `insert`s and `delete`s? :)

Try to clean up (`vacuum`).